# Why is this passing by value?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to understand the difference between pass by value and pass by reference, and I thought that I finally understand it, until I saw this code :

```
void change(char *p1)

{
    p1="new";
}

int main()

{
    char *txt1=(char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    
    txt1="original";
    printf("before :%s\n",txt1);
    change(txt1);
    printf("after :%s\n",txt1);
    
}
```

Isn't it passing an address ? and then changing it and making it point to somewhere else ?

The output is :

> before : original
>
> after : original

Why is that?

Comment: Technically, C doesn't support anything but pass by value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: "Technically"? In what aspect does it support pass by reference more than any other turing-complete language?

Comment: C, C++, Java, and any language I have ever heard of uses pass by value. But you can pass references (or pointers) by value, that makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: So many great answers to the questions, that it perhaps isn't worth adding another one - I'll just comment. (1) `printf()` is a great debugging helper. Had you added the following line: `printf("%p %s\n", &p1, p1);` _before_ and _after_ `p1="new";` as well as a similar call before and after `change(txt1);`, you would have immediately understood **_why this is passing by value_**. (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *pass-by-reference* in C. Function parameters are passed using pass-by-value. That is, `p1` itself is passed by value. You can change the content of the memory address pointed to by `p1` (`*p1`) from the called function, not `p1` itself.

To clarify, for changing the content of a variable `var`, you need to pass the address of `var`, so, if you want to change a pointer itself, you need to pass the address of the pointer to the function.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 2):

This is passing an address *as value*. To have the callee modify caller's local variable, pass address of *what should be modified*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(char **p1)

{
    *p1="new";
}

int main(void)

{
    char *txt1; /* no causing memory leak */

    txt1="original";
    printf("before :%s\n",txt1);
    change(&txt1);
    printf("after :%s\n",txt1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In function call `change(txt1);`, `txt1` is passed by value. It is copied to the parameter `p` of function `change`. This makes `pi` points to the same string as `txt1` pointing to. When new string is assigned to `p1` then `p1` changes to point to that string while `txt1` pointing previous one.

this case is very similar to

```
char *s1 = "String";
char *s2 = s1;        // Both s1 and s2 points to same string  
s2 = "Another string" // Now s2 points to "Another string" while s1 pointing to "String".
```

Beside that your code is causing memory leak. It should be like

```
char *txt1=(char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
strcpy(txt1,"original");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass By Reference and Pass By value.
[image: Pass By Reference and Pass By value.]

Comment: Hahahaaa...............Brilliant. :D

Comment: Except that there's no such thing as "pass by reference" in C. (-:

Comment: I tried to define the concept ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I've used before.  Assume the following two functions:

```
void foo( T *p ) // where T is an arbitrary data type
{
  *p = new_value(); // write new value to the thing p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;
  foo( &var );  // write new value to var
}
```

For function `foo` to update the contents of `var` (an object of type `T`) we must pass a pointer to `var` (type `T *`).

If we replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`, then the above code becomes

```
void foo( P **p )
{
  *p = new_value(); // write new value to the thing p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  P *var;
  foo( &var );  // write new value to var
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same; we want `foo` to write a new value to `var`, so we pass a pointer to `var`.  It's just that in this case, `var` is already a pointer type, so we wind up passing a pointer to a pointer.

Basically, for `foo` to update the contents of `var`, you must pass the *expression* `&var` as the argument, meaning the type of the formal parameter `p` will always have one more level of indirection than the type of `var`.

```
Type of var      Type of &var      Type of p
-----------      ------------      ---------
          T               T *            T *
        T *              T **           T **
       T **             T ***          T ***
```

etc.